# Get outputs in model.predict by name in TensorFlow-JS

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

My model has several outputs as

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def call(self, input):
        ...
        return {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}
```

`a`, `b`, and `c` all are named tensors. But after converting to TF-JS and running the model in browser my outputs seems to be a list with nameless elements in an arbitrary order. So I don't know how to match training to serving. Any ideas?

I was hoping to be able to do something like this in JS:

```
pred = model.predict(input);
a_pred = pred["a"]
```

Here is the output in JS console.
[image: Model outputs in JS console]

UPDATE1: Looking at model graph with `saved_model_cli` revealed that `SignatureDef` makes sense and has tree different outputs as expected:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['a'] tensor_info:
        ...
    outputs['b'] tensor_info:
        ...
    outputs['c'] tensor_info:
        ...
```

I guess the problem is converting to TF-JS.

UPDATE 2: Seems like in one of the examples prediction is also a list but it seems to be ordered (see [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/ef65cb58076e17343797bdc4a8f6cccab58c15a9/coco-ssd/src/index.ts#L130)).

UPDATE 3: By printing `model.outputNodes` in JS I found out that my output operations in `model.json` are called `IDENTITY, IDENTITY_1, IDENTITY_2`. So I need to figure out how to name them properly.